# Complex Numbers using relations

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, circles

> A straight line $T$ passes through $p=\sqrt{3}-2+3i$ and is a tangent to $S$, where $S$ is defined by $S=\left\{ z:\; \left| z+2-2i \right|=2,\; z\in C \right\}$. $T$ can be defined by $T=\left\{ z:\; \left| z+2-2i \right|=\left| z-d \right|,\; z\in C \right\}$. Find the complex number $d$.

---

Circle $S$ has an equation of $\left( x+2 \right)^{2}+\left( y-2 \right)^{2}=4$ and I can verify that $p$ is on $S$ by substituting $\mbox{Re}\left( p \right)$ and $\mbox{Im}\left( p \right)$.

I sketched the Argand diagram on paper, but here's the accurate diagram ($p$ is the blue dot):

[image]

Now $T$ is tangent at $\left( \sqrt{3}-2,3 \right)$, and I can get $\left| z-d \right|=2$, but that's all I could manage.

How can I find $d$?

Comment: $z$ is equidistant from the center of the circle and $d$. Take the ray from the center of the circle through $p$. The point outside the circle that is the same distance from $p$ to the center of the circle along that ray should be $d$.

Comment: @JohnDouma why is it equidistant and on that ray ?

Comment: The formula for $T$ says it is equidistant from the center of the circle and $d$. Also, the ray is perpendicular to $T$.

Comment: @JohnDouma so if $T$ is defined by $z: |z-d|=2$ and passes through $p$ then it's a common tangent between circle $S$ *and* circle $|z-d|=2$ of centre $(Re(d) , Im(d))$ and radius 2. correct ?

Comment: Set z = p into |z + 2-2i| = |z -d| and solve for d.

Comment: @inspd Correct. In fact, it's just $d=2(p-c)$ where $c$ is the center of the circle.